# Double click button Internet Explorer Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to simulate double clicking on an object in internet explorer.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<tr class="selected lead" style="height: 19px;">
<td class="sort-column" style="width: 1200px; line-height: 17px; text-indent: 19px;">
<img class="bi-tree-view-expand-icon" alt="" src="/resource/image/bid/triangle_collapsed_16.png">
<img class="icon" alt="" src=" /resource/image/bid/folder_closed_16.png">
My Content</td>
<td class="horizontal-filler" style="width: 100px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

And the VBA code (which is currently working):

```
For Each Btn In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("sort-column")
    If Btn.innerText = "My Content" Then
        Btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next Btn
```

I can see the code pressing my button, but what I need is a double click of the button. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This an internal or login based url?

Comment: Yeah, it is internal

Comment: If there is JavaScript with ondblclick event, then you can use something like: `Btn.FireEvent "ondblclick"`

Answer (score -1):

I spent some time on this and couldn't find a universal answer.  It seems any particular method that fires synthetic events may not work depending on a browser's preferred method, control inheritance, and other factors.

Assuming the event is supported, initialized, and has a listener then one of these may work for you.

If your using Chrome, Firefox, or IE 9 and below

```
Btn.FireEvents("ondblclick")
```

Except IE 8 which reportedly wants focus on the object

```
Btn.Focus
Btn.FireEvents("ondblclick")
```

And if you're on IE 10+ and above then you'll be more successful with:

```
Btn.dispatchEvent("ondblclick")
```

I'll be back after building a project to try these out.  In the meantime I hope this points you in a helpful direction.